# Why does "memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))" not clear an integer array to -1?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, integer, memset

Is it not possible to use `memset` on an array of integers? I tried the following `memset` call and didn't get the correct integer values in the `int` array.

```
int arr[5];
memset (arr, -1, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
```

Values I got are:

```
arr[0] = -1
arr[1] = 255
arr[2] = 0
arr[3] = 0
arr[4] = 0
```

Comment: might be easier to do this: int arr[5] = {-1};

Comment: @Tom Dignan: Except that only initialises the first element to -1 and all the rest to 0.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just change to `memset (arr, -1, sizeof(arr));`

**Note that for other values than 0 and -1 this would not work** since [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) sets the byte values for the block of memory that starts at the variable indicated by `*ptr` for the following `num` bytes.

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

And since `int` is represented on more than one byte, you will not get the desired value for the integers in your array.

**Exceptions:**

- 0 is an exception since, if you set all the bytes to 0, the value will be zero
- -1 is another exception since, as Patrick highlighted -1 is 0xff (=255) in int8_t and 0xffffffff in int32_t

The reason you got:

```
arr[0] = -1
arr[1] = 255
arr[2] = 0
arr[3] = 0
arr[4] = 0
```

Is because, in your case, the length of an int is 4 bytes (32 bit representation), the length of your array in bytes being 20 (=5*4), and you only set 5 bytes to -1 (=255) instead of 20.

Comment: Well, in this particular case (for -1 as a value) memset actually works. Because -1 is 0xff in int8_t and 0xffffffff in int32_t and so on. IOW: memset works fine for 0 and -1 but is not very useful for all other cases.

Comment: You are right Patrick, Thank you.. I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: @Patrick B. : it will work fine on many platforms, but not all. Not all platforms use two's complement, and you might also trigger trap representations by using `memset` to initialize an `int`.

Comment: every int whose all four bytes have the same value can use memset, not only 0 and -1

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc but are the representations besides 0 guaranteed? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11138188/895245 says yes for 0, but I think not for others because we don't know where the padding and sign bits are inside each int.

Comment: *"The reason you got: arr[0] = -1 arr[1] = 255 arr[2] = 0 arr[3] = 0 arr[4] = 0 is because..."* - Incorrect. You´d forgotten one important thing. Since `arr` is not qualified with either `static` or `extern` and is apparently declared inside a function (probably `main()`), the values of the elements of `arr` are indeterminate by definition. Even with `arr[1]` you can not be sure which values the remaining bits in the next three bytes are consisted of. Thus, printing the elements of `a[1]` to `a[4]` is a clear case of Undefined Behavior. Only at `a[0]` you will be able to know the exact result.

Answer (score 42):

Don't use `memset` to initialize anything else than single-byte data types.

At first sight, it might appear that it should work for initializing an `int` to `0` or `-1` (and on many systems it will work), but then you're not taking into account the possibility that you might generate a trap representation, causing undefined behavior, or the fact that the integer representation is [not necessarily two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c).

The correct way to initialize an array of `int` to `-1`, is to loop over the array, and set each value explicitly.

Comment: I think this answer should be pondered by a clause such as "Don't use `memset()` ... **if you want to write absolutely portable code**". Most people neither write nor intend to write portable code. Most people call code "portable" when it works for two architectures. The word "correct" in "The correct way ..." could also be changed to "portable". If you're not trying to write absolutely portable code, it's neither more nor less correct.

Comment: +1 @Complicatedseebio couldn't agree more, far too many programmers jump down peoples throats with things like 'correct', and 'stl this'. Far too often they over look what's needed by the specific problem.

Comment: @Complicated see bio @Adam : The thing is though, that initializing an array of `int` using a loop is guaranteed to work in all cases, whereas using `memset` might fail to do it properly (or worse might _appear_ to work). I won't say you can't use `memset` if you have intimate knowledge of the platforms the code will run on, and know it won't cause an issue. But I don't have such knowledge about the platforms of everyone who might read this answer, so I prefer to play it safe. I hope that balances out some of the "extremes" (for argument sake) I used in my answer.

Comment: Upvote for Sander, I didn't understand why the -1 wasn't working for me until I realized the machine I was working with wasn't 2-complement.

Comment: @capitano666 - just curious - what processor ("machine") were you using?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: If the array is of a type `int*_t`, it data is guaranteed to be stored in two's-complement without padding.  As for non-two's-complement machines, I would be very surprised if there exist *any* conforming C99 implementations that are used to run production code but don't use two's-complement.  Unisys may still be upgrading their compilers, but the manual I read didn't list any unsigned type longer than 36 bits.

Comment: @supercat : whether there are 0 or 1000 such implementations that are currently in use, does not change my point of view. I don't know how many there are, nor do I know whether readers of my answer use such implementations (archaic or otherwise), nor do I know whether such implementations might make a comeback in the future. All I know is that my recommendation will work on any conforming implementation.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Any code which follows the common advice of favoring uint32_t etc. over int, long, etc. will be limited to implementations which store signed versions of the named-size types in two's-complement format (I think the Standard should have allowed implementations to define uint32_t if they have a 32-bit unsigned type with no padding or trap representations, without regard for whether they have a corresponding two's-complement signed type, but the Standard forbids that).  I do not think there is value in adding any complexity to code for purposes of supporting...

Comment: ...implementations that do not exist and are extremely unlikely to exist in future.

Comment: @Frederick, I'm afraid I don't remember what I was working with 3 years ago, maybe it was a Cubieboard2 [Allwinner sun7i (A20) CPU], but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: IMO, besides the portable argument, the problem with "I know this works" is that it hides the programmer's intention, relying on an implicit assumption any reader of that code must know to interpret the code.

Comment: `memset()` is ok to initialize complex data types **as long as you use it to initialize to zero**. You are saying that the correctness of `memset()` depends on the datatype. But this is simply not the case. You can either `memset()` a byte buffer to any byte value, or you can `memset()` an object of any type to `0`. You only get into trouble when you violate both rules at the same time.

Comment: Beside your great hint and to come back to the provided example, there is apparently already undefined behavior since the OP attempt to print indeterminate values.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica : even for initializing to `0` it's not ok. A [pointer with all bits set to `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714377) doesn't necessarily represent a null pointer. A [floating point with all bits set to `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53783149) doesn't necessarily represent `0.0`. Before standardization, even integers with all bits set to `0` didn't necessarily represent the value `0` (due to trap representations, and no exception for all `0` bits). Granted, on the vast majority of systems this won't be an issue, but better be safe than sorry.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker `memset(..., 0, ...)` is just as good/evil as `calloc()`. And you don't advocate against the use of `calloc()`, do you?

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica : your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker At least you are consistent, then :-) Myself, I use both `memset(..., 0, ...)` and `calloc()` where appropriate. But I'm usually working on X86 anyways, no exotic platforms that might implement `NULL` with a nonzero bit pattern. I won't doubt that such platforms may exist. Would be quite a braindead platform, though, as C mandates that `NULL` compares equal to `0`.

Answer (score 11):

gcc provides a good array initialization shortcut

`int arr[32] = {[0 ... 10] = 3, [11 ... 31] = 4}`

mind the space before and after `...`

Answer (score 6):

Why the division?

```
memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr));
```

Your version, `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)`, gives you the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Note that `memset()` sets the value of the _bytes_ at the addressed location, not how many "items."  You'd want to set the 5 ints worth of bytes to `-1`.  Doing so will just happen to set the int values to `-1` as a coincidence of the format.

Comment: @Jeff: indeed, coincidence, because an int of -1 is usually $FFFFFFFF (assuming 32 bit int and two's complement) and a byte of -1 is $FF. Had he chosen -2 ($FE), it would have become $FEFEFEFE, which is an int of -16843010.

Answer (score 4):

You can save yourself some typing by initializing the array directly:

```
int arr[5] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

That line is shorter than the memset, and it also works.

Comment: +1 for array initializer, although it's useful just for few values.

Comment: One could also abbreviate that and omit the explicit specification of the amount of elements, since the compiler detects the amount of elements by the number of initializations: `int arr[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};` .

Answer (score 1):

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

This function works well on most systems when applied to set char array.
It sets the first num BYTES of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char). [memset-C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/?kw=memset)
It operates one byte each time. So it works fine if you assign the second arguments with a int value no more than 0xff.

As for your version, the third arguments is the number of array elements, so you got your output.
Actually the truth is you are supposed to assign the third arguments the NUMBER OF BYTES you want.

So the correct version should be like this:

```
memset (arr, -1, sizeof(arr));
```