# Zeroing out anonymous union

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, unions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set all bytes of int to (unsigned char)0, guaranteed to represent zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138188/set-all-bytes-of-int-to-unsigned-char0-guaranteed-to-represent-zero)

I have the following anonymous union inside a struct:

```
union
{
    unsigned value;
    char name[4];
};
```

Can I replace the following code:

```
name[0] = 0;
name[1] = 0;
name[2] = 0;
name[3] = 0;
```

With the following code?

```
value = 0;
```

Comment: I think it boils down to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined - right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore no. This is writing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes, but I'm assuming he later wants to also read from it, otherwise there would be no need for the zeroing, right?

Comment: If it's only a matter of byte representation and writing, this question is very relevant: **[Set all bytes of int to (unsigned char)0, guaranteed to represent zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138188/set-all-bytes-of-int-to-unsigned-char0-guaranteed-to-represent-zero)**

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't want to go into this again, and I'm off to lunch, but you can alias anything with a pointer or reference to char. I've mentioned this before here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10272228/46642 This is a contentious topic, so don't take my word as proof.

Comment: Basically, I don't see why `*reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value)` is ok, but `name[0]` is UB.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, no it doesn't boil down to that question there, because here it is asked for C++ and C at the same time. They are different with that respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simple case it's the same, but only because (most likely) `int` (and `unsigned` is short for `unsigned int`) is 32 bits (i.e. four bytes). If the array is larger, or `int` is only 16 bits it will not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is better:

```
memset(name, 0, max(sizeof(name), sizeof(int)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In C you'd better do

```
union
{
   char name[sizeof(unsigned)];
   unsigned value;
};
```

Now an implicit initializer, e.g if you initialize the surrounding `struct`, will always initialize your name field to all `0`. And provided `unsigned` has no padding bits (which is very likely) an initialization or assignment of `0` to `value` will also always zero out `name`.

Rules for C++ are different, it seems that there reading from a different field that you have written to is UB.

Answer (score 0):

between

```
name[0] = 0;
```

and

```
name[1] = 0;
```

and

```
name[2] = 0;
```

and

```
name[3] = 0;
```

other functions can change other bytes. So,

```
value = 0;
```

is more secure i think

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if `sizeof(unsigned)==4`.

Comment: Or if the size is 8, etc.... anything >= 4.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is right if you're on a 64-bit machine. If not you will overwrite the first 2 characters from name, because on 32-bit machines `unsigned`'s size is 2 byte not 4 (or higher).