# Does the C++ standard require the maximum of unsigned integer numbers to be of the form 2^N-1?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-lawyer, unsigned

For `T` so that `std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_unsigned<T>::value` is `true`, does the C++ standard guarantee that :

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::max() == 2^(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits)-1
```

in the mathematical sense? I am looking for a proof of that based on quotes from the standard.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125650/what-do-the-c-and-c-standards-say-about-bit-level-integer-representation-and-m) could be helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++ specifies the ranges of the integral types by reference to the C standard. The C standard says:

> For unsigned integer types other than `unsigned char`, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need not be any of the latter). If there are *N* value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2<sup>*N* − 1</sup>, so that objects of that type shall be capable of
>   representing values from 0 to 2<sup>*N* − 1</sup> using a pure binary representation; this shall be known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.

Moreover, C++ requires:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Putting all this together, we find that an unsigned integral type has *n* value bits, represents the values in the range [0, 2<sup>*n*</sup>) and obeys the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

Comment: So why are they saying "value bits in the object representation" one time, and "bits in the value representation" the other time?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: The two language standards have developed slightly different styles of phrasing what is essentially the same idea. The first quote is from C11, the second from the C++ WD.

Answer (score 15):

I believe that this is implied by `[basic.fundamental]/4` (N3337):

> Unsigned integers, declared `unsigned`, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n` where `n` is the number
>   of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Comment: It is indeed and follows directly from `MAX = -1 = 2^n  - 1` modulo `2^n`.

Comment: If MAX is less than 2^n-1, then the quoted section implies that MAX+1 is not zero and hence that MAX is not the maximum - which would be a contradiction.

Comment: Strictly speaking "obeying the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n`" describes arithmetic operators and equality relations for the type, not the set of values that can be taken. Mathematically, the values used in modular arithmetic are _congruence classes_ of integers, and can be implemented using any complete set of representative values in the classes. Although I know it doesn't (and prefers to invoke undefined behaviour), the standard _could have_ chosen to stipulate that `signed int` obey the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n` as well (then only `<` etc would distinguish `int` from `unsigned`).