# Position 2D array bug as parameter causes memory dumps

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is my program in C++, which accepts an 2D array `a[m][n]`. If an element `a[i][j]` is zero, then set all the `ith` row and `jth` column elements to zero.

This is code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class SetZero{
public:
    static void setZero(int **, int , int);
};

void SetZero::setZero(int ** a, int m, int n){
    int i, j, k;
    int ** b = new int *[m]; //flags to identify whether set to zero or not.

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        b[i] = new int[n];
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            b[i][j] = 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if(a[i][j] == 0 && b[i][j]){//DUMP here. If I change it to (a+i)[j], then works.
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    a[i][k] = 0;//but there is NO dump here. Weird!
                    b[i][k] = 0;
                }
                for(k = 0; k < m; k++){
                    a[k][j] = 0;
                    b[k][j] = 0;
                }
                j = n;//break. next row loop.
            }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        delete[] b[i];
    delete[] b;
}

int main(){
    int a[4][5];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){//create an 2D array
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    SetZero::setZero((int **)a, 4, 5);//type cast.

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){//print result
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Environment: WIN8 Visual Studio 2012.

**Edit:**
The program can compile but cannot execute normally. It will stop when it reaches  `if(a[i][j] == 0 && b[i][j]){`

The error message is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x012875DD in CCLC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x0000004B.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Do you get a segmentation fault? An incorrect result? Have you tried running the code through a debugger?

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Comment: @GWW Yes. The program stops when it reaches "if(a[i][j] == 0 && b[i][j]){". I don't know why.

Comment: Have you looked at the values of `i` and `j` using the debugger to see if they have unexpected values?

Comment: @GWW Yes. i and j are all zero. No problem. I have add information about the problem when executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetZero::setZero((int **)a, 4, 5)
```

`a` is not an array of pointers, it is simply a 2 dimensional array.

notice how the access violation is reading address 0x0000004B? that's 75, a number between 0 and 99 :) because you are treating a 2 dimensional array (which is just a one dimensional array with a neat way of accessing it) as an array of arrays, it is taking one of the values in your array (75) to be the address of a sub array, then trying to read the non existent array at address 75 (or 0x0000004B)

I suggest that you 'flatten' your arrays and work with them as one dimensional arrays, which I find simpler:

```
void SetZero::setZero(int * a, int m, int n){
int i, j, k;
int * b = new int [m*n]; //flags to identify whether set to zero or not.

for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
    b[i] = new int[n];
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        b[i*n+j] = 1;
}

for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if(a[i*n+j] == 0 && b[i*n+j]){//DUMP here. If I change it to (a+i)[j], then works.
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++){
                a[i*n+k] = 0;//but there is NO dump here. Weird!
                b[i*n+k] = 0;
            }
            for(k = 0; k < m; k++){
                a[k*n+j] = 0;
                b[k*n+j] = 0;
            }
            j = n;//break. next row loop.
        }


delete[] b;
}

int main(){
int a[4*5];

srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){//create an 2D array
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        a[i*5+j] = rand() % 100;
        cout << a[i*5+j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

SetZero::setZero(a, 4, 5);//type cast.

cout << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){//print result
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        cout << a[i*5+j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion about the SetZero().  There is a function called [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) which allows you to set all bytes to a specific value given a starting pointer and the range.  This function could make your SetZero() function more cleaner:

---

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Fill block of memory. Sets the first `num` bytes of the block of memory pointed by `ptr` to the specified `value` (interpreted as an unsigned char).

***Parameters***

- ptr: Pointer to the block of memory to fill.
- value: Value to be set. The value is passed as an int, but the function fills the block of memory using the unsigned char conversion of this value.
- num: Number of bytes to be set to the value, size_t is an unsigned integral type.

---

For example, the following code block from your program:

```
 for (k = 0; k < n; k++){
   a[i][k] = 0;//but there is NO dump here. Weird!
   b[i][k] = 0;
 }
```

can be achieved by `memset` in a cleaner way:

```
 memset(a[i], 0, n * sizeof(int));
 memset(b[i], 0, n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `memset` doesn't work for `setZero` function. Since I can determine the `num` parameter. `sizeof(b[i])` doesn't work.

Comment: @Zack: I have included an example from your code in my answer, hopefully it will make it more clear.

Comment: Yes. I see. IT REALLY WORKS. But if I want to set all `elements` to `1` but `0`. How can I implement it except `for loop`?

Comment: @Zack: Then memset won't work as it's processing unit is bit.

Comment: @Zack: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array) is some more details in case you're interested.