# Initializing C dynamic arrays

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

How do I initialize a dynamic array allocated with malloc? Can I do this:

```
int *p;
p = malloc(3 * sizeof(*p));
p = {0, 1, 2};

...

free(p);
```

Or do I need to do something like this:

```
int *p, x;
p = malloc(3 * sizeof(*p));
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    p[x] = 0;

...

free(p);
```

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you mean `p[x] = x;` instead of `p[x] = 0;`?

Comment: The second method is the correct way. The first one gets a compiler error, doesn't it?

Comment: http://fydo.net/gamedev/dynamic-arrays shows how to use dynamic arrays. in fact its a very popular link and you can find it with any major search engine...

Comment: I think the more tedious way is the only way to do it. I tried the first one and it doesn't compile (After commenting the '...') No many shortcuts in 'C' I guess.ac

Comment: I have heard that some programmers use the memset() function for something like this.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in the first place

Comment: @JustinChadwell You can not use `memset` for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array?rq=1

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: If someone wants to clear the array using 0, `memset` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @phoxis Since we don't have any details on the system being used, we don't really know it will work properly as explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7202857 although in most settings you are probably ok

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Those are valid causes, definitely not necessarily the number representation is two's compliment and integers may have padding also.

Answer (score 27):

You need to allocate a block of memory and use it as an array as:

```
int *arr = malloc (sizeof (int) * n); /* n is the length of the array */
int i;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  arr[i] = 0;
}
```

If you need to initialize the array with zeros you can also use the `memset` function from C standard library (declared in `string.h`).

```
memset (arr, 0, sizeof (int) * n);
```

Here `0` is the constant with which every locatoin of the array will be set. Note that the last argument is the number of bytes to be set the the constant. Because each location of the array stores an integer therefore we need to pass the total number of bytes as this parameter.

Also if you want to clear the array to zeros, then you may want to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. `calloc` will return the memory block after setting the allocated byte locations to zero.

After you have finished, free the memory block `free (arr)`.

**EDIT1**

Note that if you want to assign a particular integer in locations of an integer array using `memset` then it will be a problem. This is because `memset` will interpret the array as a byte array and assign the byte you have given, to every byte of the array. So if you want to store say 11243 in each location then it will not be possible.

**EDIT2**

Also note why every time setting an int array to 0 with `memset` may not work: [Why does "memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))" not clear an integer array to -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array/7202857#7202857)  as pointed out by @Shafik Yaghmour

Answer (score 23):

Instead of using

```
int * p;
p = {1,2,3};
```

we can use

```
int * p;
p =(int[3]){1,2,3};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Super useful if each individual element has its own value what cannot be computed in any way, so you end-up writing initialization for each element individually.
One question: is it part of any C standard, or is it compiler specific?

Comment: This is not a drop-in replacement for a `malloc`-ed array! The compound literal you're using to initialize `p` has automatic storage duration. It will be freed automatically at the end of the block, and calling `free` on it manually is undefined behavior. You can't use this to allocate an array you're going to return, or to allocate anything that has to persist beyond the current block.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use the syntax you have suggested.  If you have a C99 compiler, though, you can do this:

```
int *p;

p = malloc(3 * sizeof p[0]);
memcpy(p, (int []){ 0, 1, 2 }, 3 * sizeof p[0]);
```

If your compiler does not support C99 compound literals, you need to use a named template to copy from:

```
int *p;

p = malloc(3 * sizeof p[0]);
{
    static const int p_init[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    memcpy(p, p_init, 3 * sizeof p[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

p = {1,2,3} is wrong.

You can never use this:

```
int * p;
p = {1,2,3};
```

loop is right

```
int *p,i;
p = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    p[i] = i;
```