# memset sets random values

Tags: c++, memset

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int win[11];
    std::memset(win, 1, sizeof(win));
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        std::cout << win[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think there is no logic flaw here?  But instead of getting a string of `1` printed, I got `16843009`.

If I change the `memset` to `std::memset(win, 0, sizeof(win))`.  Then everything is as expected.  The content of win is all zeros.

Am I missing something here?

I'm using `g++ 4.7.3` on `Ubuntu 13.04`.

Sorry for this duplicated question.

Here is the answer.  Thanks

[Why does "memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))" not clear an integer array to -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array)

Comment: Can I flag my own question as duplicated?

Comment: @DyP Yes. I have different keywords so I didn't find it till minutes ago

Comment: (That comment has been created automatically because I voted to close as dup.)

Comment: Really, "random"? What are you, the NSA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int`s are usually four bytes long. But `memset` sets the value of individual bytes, so you're setting each value to 0x01010101, which just so happens to equal 16843009.

Comment: "Integers are four bytes long" on this particular platform.

Comment: @DyP Yes yes, I guess I should clarify...

Answer (score 3):

The `memset` function writes over memory without understanding its structure in any way. If you write a bunch of random `1`'s all over an accounting report, will that make the report show that the company has spent $1? I don't think so. Maybe it will show `111111` dollars. Maybe not. Who knows.

To modify an object's value intelligently, you have to understand its structure. The `memset` function does not understand the structure of `win` and just scribbles `1` all over its bytes. What that means, `memset` does not know or care.