# Does Standard define null pointer constant to have all bits set to zero?

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer

( I'm quoting ISO/IEC 9899:201x )

Here we see that, integer constant expression has an integer type:

> 6.6 Constant expressions
>
> 6.
> *An integer constant expression shall have integer type* and shall only have operands
> that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof
> expressions whose results are integer constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating
> constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
> expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

Then this holds true for any integer type:

> 6.2.6.2 Integer types
>
> 5.
> The values of any padding bits are unspecified.A valid (non-trap) object representation
> of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the
> corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value. *For any integer type,
> the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value
> zero in that type.*

Then we see that a null pointer constant is defined using an integer constant expression with the value 0.

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 3.
> *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> void*, is called a null pointer constant.* If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function.

Therefore the null pointer constant must have all it's bits set to zero.

But there are many answers online and on StackOverflow that say that that isn't true.

I have a hard time believing them given the quoted parts.

( Please answer using references to the latest Standard )

Comment: To start with, 6.2.6.2/5 says "all bits zero" results in 0, not 0 must be all bits zero. Moreover, the result when you convert an integer to a pointer is implementation-defined (6.3.2.3/5), so the result of 0 cast to type `void *` isn't necessarily going to be all bits zero.

Comment: @T.C. That sounds like an oxymoron. If all bits zero represent a value `0`, then a value `0` must have all it's bits zero.

Comment: @2501 No, because there's not necessarily a one-to-one correlation between the value and the bit pattern.

Comment: @2501: You could have a 24 bit int stored in 32 bits, with 8 padding bits that are ignored. All bits including padding bits zero is 0. But 0 might have some padding bits not set.

Comment: @2501: There must be a value of zero that has all bits zero, but there's no guarantee that there's only one zero -- there may be other bit patterns that are also zero, and using a `0` literal may get you one of those other patterns rather than the all 0 bits pattern.  The real question is whether the all zero bits representation will be a null pointer or not, which the standard doesn't really address.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That is a good point. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisDodd even if it was guaranteed, I don't think you can then guarantee that for example (assuming here `long` and `void *` having same size and representation): `long a = 0; void *p = (void *) a;` that here `p` is a null pointer in all systems.

Comment: @ouah: True, but what you'd *really* like the standard to guarantee (which it doesn't) is that calling `memset(p, 0, size)` to clear out a struct will set all the pointers in the struct to null.

Comment: It would be interesting to have an example of a complier (with the last 10 years) that does not use an all zero `NULL`.  I see @ouah link, but it has no dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, NULL doesn't have to be all bits zero.

N1570 6.3.2.3 Pointers paragraph 3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   void *, is called a null pointer constant. 66) If a null pointer **constant is converted to a
>   pointer type**, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

See my emphasis above: Integer `0` is *converted* if necessary, it doesn't have to have same bit presentation.

Note 66 on bottom of the page says:

> 66) The macro NULL is defined in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.

Which leads us to a paragraph of that chapter:

> The macros are
>
> **NULL**
>
> which expands to an **implementation-defined** null pointer constant

And what is more, on Annex J.3.12 (Portability issues, Implementation-defined behaviour, Library functions)  says:

> — The null pointer constant to which the macro NULL expands (7.19).

Comment: The first statement is somewhat confusing because `NULL` (the null pointer *constant*) does have to be 0, but the *null pointer* does not.

Comment: I have heard of examples where registers are memory mapped on a small processor, starting with address 0.  As a result, that particular patform defines null to be 255 rather than 0, because they wanted to preserve the ability to refer to the first register.

Answer (score 7):

> Does Standard define null pointer constant to have all bits set to zero?

No, it doesn't. No paragraph of the C Standard impose such a requirement.

```
void *p = 0;
```

`p` for example is a null pointer, but the Standard does not require that the object `p` must have all bit set.

For information the c-faq website mentions some systems with non-zero null pointer representations here: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: @Jasen +1 - that is promotion.  Good point - the bits in the object DO in fact change.  int to double promotion is another example.

Answer (score 4):

Asking about the representation of a null pointer constant is quite pointless.

A null pointer constant either has an integer type or the type void*. Whatever it is, it is a *value*. It is not an object. Values don't have a representation, only objects have. We can only talk about representations by taking the address of an object, casting it to char* or unsigned char*, and looking at the bytes. We can't do that with a null pointer constant. As soon as it is assigned to an object, it's not a null pointer constant anymore.

Comment: it's not entriley pointless, for example if I use calloc() to allocate an array of char* (ie; a `char**`), being able to rely on them being initialized to null could be useful.  as has been shown, such an approach is non-portable.

Answer (score 3):

A major limitation of the C standard is that because the authors want to avoid prohibiting compilers from behaving in any ways that any production code anywhere might be relying upon, it fails to specify many things which programmers need to know.  As a consequence, it is often necessary make assumptions about things which are not specified by the standard, but match the behaviors of common compilers.  The fact that all of the bytes comprising a null pointer are zero is one such assumption.

Nothing in the C standard specifies anything about the bit-level representation of any pointer beyond the fact that every possible value of each and every data type--including pointers--will be representable as a sequence of `char` values(*).  Nonetheless, on nearly all common platforms platforms zeroing out all the bytes associated with a structure is equivalent to setting all the members to the static default values for their types (the default value for a pointer being null).  Further, code which uses `calloc` to receive a zeroed-out a block of RAM for a collection of structures will often be much faster than code which uses `malloc` and then has to manually clear every member of every structure, or which uses `calloc` and but still manually clears every non-integer member of every structure.

I would suggest therefore that in many cases it is perfectly reasonable to write code targeted for those dialects of C where null pointers are stored as all-bytes-zero, and have as a documented requirement that it will not work on dialects where that is not the case.  Perhaps someday the ISO will provide a standard means by which such requirements could be documented in machine-readable form (such that every compiler would be required to either abide by a program's stated requirements or refuse compilation), but so far as I know none yet exists.

(*) From what I understand, there's some question as to whether compilers are required to honor that assumption anymore.  Consider, for example:

```
int funcomp(int **pp, int **qq)
{
    int *p,*q;
    p = (int*)malloc(1234);
    *pp = p;
    free(p);
    q = (int*)malloc(1234);
    *qq = q;
    *q = 1234;
    if (!memcmp(pp, qq, sizeof p))
      return *p;
    return 0;
 }
```

Following `free(p)` any attempt to access `*p` will be Undefined Behavior. Although there's a significant likelihood that `q` will receive the exact same bit pattern as `p`, nothing in the standard would require that `p` must be considered a valid alias for `q` even in that scenario.  On the other hand, it also seems strange to say that two variables of the same type can hold the exact same bits without their contents being equivalent.  Thus, while it's clearly natural that the function would be allowed to either return 0 along with values of `*pp` and `*qq` that don't compare bit-wise equal, or 1234 along with values of `*pp` and `*qq` that do compare bit-wise equal, the Standard would seem to allow the function to behave arbitrarily if both `malloc` happen to yield bitwise-equivalent values.