# Tail of linked list not being set to NULL using Calloc?

Tags: c, linked-list

Let's say that I have a struct setup like this:

```
typedef struct node{
   char data;
   struct node *next;
} node;
```

I'm setting up the node like this:

```
node *createNode(char data){
   node *init = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
   init->data = data;
   init->next = NULL;

   return init;
}
```

And there's some insert function that takes data and inserts it into the node.
Shouldn't the reference

```
node->next->next
```

Always be set NULL because of calloc(zeroes out the memory block)?
I'm getting a value that isn't NULL in the node->next->next block and I'm confused why this is happening.

Edit:

```
void insertNode(node *head, char data) { 
     while(node->next != NULL) 
           node = node->next; 
     node->data = data; 
     node->next = createNode(); 
}
```

The main function just loops through a string and uses the node pointer as the first parameter, I can't post anymore than this since it's getting too close to my actual code that I'm working on right now.

Comment: `calloc` sets `node->next` to `NULL`. Accessing `node->next->next` when `node->next` is `NULL` is undefined behavior, i.e. don't do that.

Comment: calloc is useless here.

Comment: You use `calloc` and then set `init->next = NULL;`. No need to do that.

Comment: Is useless because both `struct` members were explicitly initialised.

Comment: Given the typedef, `node->next->next` is a syntax error

Comment: Thanks for the calloc advice,  what if I'm supposed to code against node->next->next?  It would throw a segfault if you tried to access node->next->next->data access right?  I'm just trying to think where I'm messing up in my code that's not producing a NULL tail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718190/905902 No. a NULL pointer value is not necessarily represented by *all-zeros* (so:in this case, the calloc() is more or less useless. It won't harm, but justa malloc() would do. Plus: proper initialisation to NULL,of course)

Comment: Show us your insert function and the test code that yields the erroneous result.

Comment: `node->next->next->data` is bad: check every pointer in that chain.

Comment: void insertNode(node *head, char data)                  
{              
    while(node->next != NULL)                   
          node = node->next;                
    node->data = data;          
    node->next = createNode();             
}

Comment: "I'm getting a value that isn't NULL in the node->next->next block" --> add that code to the post  that demonstrates this.

Comment: See also http://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html

Comment: @pinacoloda, edit your question to show the code, don't add it to the comments.

Comment: `createNode();` is an error (missing argument). Please read [mcve].