# Strange problem with memset, why is it zeroing my variable?

Tags: c

I have a strange problem with my code. This is what I'm doing:

```
out_t *out[c-1];
memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out)*(unsigned int)c-1); //this function is causing me a problem

int Ilosc[c-1];
memset(&Ilosc, 0, sizeof(Ilosc)*(unsigned int)c-1);
```

My program causes a segfault when ran. I examined this inside a debugger:

```
(gdb)
main () at ..\main.c:103
103         memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out)*(unsigned int)c-1);
(gdb) print c
$23 = 5
(gdb) s
105         int Ilosc[c-1];
(gdb) print c
$24 = 0
```

Basically, after my first memset my variable c is now equal to zero, which causes the second memset to not work. I have absolutely no idea what causes that, does anybody know what it could be?

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(out_t)` on an array of `out_t*`?

Comment: Change your `memset` to: `memset(out,0,sizeof(out))` and `memset(Ilosc,0,sizeof(Ilosc))`. You are taking `sizeof(entire_array) * array_count)` which is N times the necessary amount

Comment: using `= { 0 };` instead of `memset` would avoid all this hullabaloo

Comment: @M.M In particular, it would also be *correct*, unlike the code that assumes `NULL` to have an all-zero bitwise representation.

Comment: @EOF True, although IMO in 2018 for your average poster that is more of a historical curiosity than something that needs to be allowed for in the code

Comment: @M.M The reason why I'm using memset instead of straight initializing because the value of variable c comes from another function, and if I try to initialize it like that it gives me an "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized". I've got it working, thank you very much!

Comment: @EOF I want to initialize second array to zeros, that's an int array, but I indeed wanted to initialize the first array, the array of pointers, to NULLs, but when I did that (I used argument NULL instead of 0 in the first memset), I got "expected 'int' but argument is of type 'void *'. I suppresed this warning using "(int) NULL" as an argument of memset, is it a correct way to do that?

Comment: @kunek If you can't initialize with `= {0};`, then the only standard-conforming way is to iterate over the elements of the array (e.g. with a `for`-loop).

Comment: @EOF I got that, thanks for your input!

Comment: Aside from all the other comments, `sizeof(out)*(unsigned int)c-1` is `(sizeof(out) * (unsigned)c) - 1`, not `(sizeof(out) * (unsigned(c - 1))`. So even if you had used `(sizeof *out)` instead of `sizeof(out)`, you would still be overwriting all but one of the bytes of the following stack slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the `sizeof` operator to an array, it gives you the size of the *whole array in bytes*, not the size of one element.  Because you're multiplying this value by the number of array elements, you're writing far past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can properly clear each array as follows:

```
out_t *out[c-1];
memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));

int Ilosc[c-1];
memset(Ilosc, 0, sizeof(Ilosc));
```

Or better still:

```
out_t *out[c-1] = { NULL };
int Ilosc[c-1] = { 0 };
```

This will initialize all array elements to NULL or 0 without having to call `memset`.

Comment: The reason why I'm using memset instead of straight initializing because the value of variable c comes from another function, and if I try to initialize it like that it gives me an "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized". I've got it working, thank you very much!

Comment: @kunek Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Since when is all-bits-zero guaranteed to be a valid null-pointer? [Actually, it isn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714377/does-standard-define-null-pointer-constant-to-have-all-bits-set-to-zero)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `out` as an array of pointers to `out_t`, but your `memset` operation is treating it as an array of `out_t`, not as an array of `out_t*`. Probably you want to do either:

```
out_t out[c-1]; // out is an array of out_t
memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out));
```

or

```
out_t *out[c-1]; // out is an array of out_t*
memset(&out, 0, sizeof(out));
```