# Use Initialization List in C after declaration

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, declaration

I am learning C and some things confuse me and the books I have read didn't really help in clarifying the problem I have.

So here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

// gcc -std=c99 stackoverflow-example.c

int main () {

    // declare variable array1
    int array1[ARRAY_SIZE];
    // declare and init variable array2
    int array2[ARRAY_SIZE] = {}; // for integers, the default value is 0

    // not initialized
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        // can be anything, not guaranteed to be 0
        printf("array1[%d]: %d\n", i, array1[i]);
    }

    // initialized with initialization list
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        // element == 0
        printf("array2[%d]: %d\n", i, array2[i]);
    }

    // This is the part that confuses me.
    // array1 = {};  // error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    // array1[] = {};  // same error

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is there a handy way to initialize this array after its declaration? Or the only way to set every element in `array1` is with a for loop, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    array1[i] = 0;

// initialized with a for loop
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    // now it's guaranteed to be 0
    printf("array1[%d]: %d\n", i, array1[i]);
```

I really appreciate your help. I know it's somewhat of a noob question, but it came up as I was trying to get more comfortable with the C language and tried some non-book-example code.

If you suspect, that there might be something fundamental that I didn't get, please let me know, I'll read up on it.

Comment: I think you should try the `memset` function. It is optimized to initialize blocks of data with a constant value.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Though, it works only for initializing with 0 (know I used 0 initialized array in my example, so it'd work actually). and -1 [(and it's not really guaranteed)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7202857/4541492). Thank you, nonetheless.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You're right, `memset` is specific for arrays of bytes.

Comment: in C, a variable (array or struct or ...) can only be 'initialized' when it is declared.   Thereafter, it must be assigned.   When assigning, without using functions like `memset()`, each entity must be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) can be done once and only at declaration time, any value *storing* after that is assignment or copying.

A brace-enclosed initializer list can be used for initialization of arrays only at the declaration time.

For an individual element of an array, (a scalar item), the rule is: (*quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9*)

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.

and an empty list `{}` is not a valid initializer (*expression*) for a scalar. hence you got the error.

So, for an already defined array, the *re-setting* has to be done either

- member-by-member, via a loop
- using [`memcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), or [memset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) if so permits.

Comment: Then let me rephrase: Is there a way (kind of like a "syntactic sugar", though I know this is not what C is famous about) to *assign* various elements of an array after declaration?

Comment: @VinceVarga well, memset() may be your friend, but not for different values, I fear.

Comment: `memset()` will set all the bytes to the same value, which is probably not much use if you want to set integer elements to the same non-zero value. You can usually get away with using `memset()` for setting all the elements to an integer `0`, but strictly speaking, that is non-portable. For setting elements to the same non-zero value, a loop is probably your best bet. For setting elements to different values, it can be done with individual assignments, or by using `memcpy()` to copy everything over from another (possibly `const`) array.

Comment: In addition to what I wrote about `memcpy()` in my previous comment, the second (source) parameter of `memcpy()` could be a compound literal array, e.g. `memcpy(array1, (int[ARRAY_SIZE]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Thank you, Ian, it appears to me that the `memcpy` is the closes thing I got to what I wanted originally