# Does calloc() of a double field always evaluate to 0.0?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, double, calloc

- Does `calloc()` of a double field always evaluate to `0.0`?

*Furthermore*:

- Does `calloc()` of a `float` field always evaluate to `0.0f`?
- Does `calloc()` of an `int` or `unsigned int` field always evaluate to `0`?

*That is*, will the `assert()` below always succeed on all platforms?

```
double* d = calloc(1, sizeof(double));
assert(*d == 0.0);
free(d);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) sets all bytes of the allocated memory to zero.

As it happens, that's also the valid [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (which is the most common format for floating point values on computers) representation for `0.0`.

IIRC there's no part of the C specification that requires an implementation to use IEEE754, so to be picky it's not portable. In reality though, it is (and if you're ever going to work on a non-IEEE754 system then you should have gathered enough experience to already know this and how to solve such problems).

Also note that this also is valid for pointers. On all systems you're likely to come in contact with, a null pointer should be equal to `0`. But there might be systems where it isn't, but if you work on such systems you should already know about it (and if you use `NULL` then it should not be a problem).

Comment: Thanks for the IEEE 754 reference.

Comment: I'm not sure about your null pointer explanation. After all, the C language guarantees that a null pointer will equal `0`, even on those unusual systems where `calloc` is not guaranteed to initialize a pointer-sized object to a null pointer value. I'm not sure what you mean by "(and if you use `NULL` then it should not be a problem)".

Comment: @IanAbbott It might be that the integer literal `0` have been recognized as a null pointer (as it is in C++, but then it must be the actual literal `0` not an integer variable with all zero bits) in later revisions of the C standard, but the portable null pointer is, has, and always will be the macro `NULL`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It doesn't need to be a literal `0`. It just needs to be an *integer constant expression* with value 0, or such an expression cast to `void *`. You are correct that a value 0 stored in an *lvalue* of integer type cannot be compared to a pointer value.

Answer (score 7):

C11 documentation has this explicit notice for `calloc`

> Footnotes
>
> 296. Note that this need not be the same as the representation of
>      floating-point zero or a null pointer constant.

In practice, all zero bits is a (or the) representation for 0.0 on all major platforms as they use IEEE 754 representation. Yes, this will hold on Intel, ARM, Linux, Windows, Mac, Raspberry PI, the smartphones.

Answer (score 2):

All bytes zero for a `float` does not mean `0.0`. From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)

> Initialization to all bits zero does not guarantee that a floating-point or a pointer would be initialized to 0.0 and the null pointer value, respectively (although that is true on all common platforms)

Comment: I should have read cppreference.com for `calloc()` before asking the question. I had looked at cplusplus.com only. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) deliberately avoids specifying the way that `float` and `double` are represented:

> 6.2.6.1 General
>
> 1. The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

Therefore, you have no guarantee that `calloc` would produce 0.0 values.

Representation of unsigned integers, on the other hand, is specified as follows:

> If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different
>   power of 2 between 1 and 2<sup>N−1</sup>, so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2<sup>N − 1</sup> using a pure binary representation.

Therefore, the value of `calloc`-ed `unsugned int` is guaranteed to be zero.

Comment: Fascinating about `unsigned int`.