# How to initialize a buffer of large size to all bits on?

Tags: c, bit, memcpy, twos-complement

I am trying to initialize a bitmap to all bits on. My idea was to initialize an array of the buffer size and then use `memcpy`; however:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main () {
  int i[SIZE] = { ~0 };
  for (int j = 0 ; j < SIZE ; j++) {
    printf("%d\n", i[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
-1
0
0
0
0
```

my expectation was that I would see all `-1`. Why does this not work, and how can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
int i[SIZE] = { ~0 };
```

Explicitly initializes only the first element of the array to `~0`.  The rest are implicitly set to 0.

If you want all bits to be set, you need to use `memset`:

```
memset(i, ~0, sizeof i);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this always guaranteed to work for `~0` on signed and unsigned types? I saw that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/why-does-memsetarr-1-sizeofarr-sizeofint-not-clear-an-integer-array-t) mentioned some prohibitiveness around `memset`.

Comment: On a 2's complement system -- and they all are these days -- yes.

Comment: Can I ask why it wouldn't work on a non- 2's complement system? It seems like the `~0` is interpreted as `unsigned char`, so I'm not sure why it would make a difference?

Comment: @user129393192, See [here](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/f72bd6a67a25b4d71fc1a68b895da588)

Comment: Got it. That's very strange. The `-0` explanation made it very clear. I never would have expected that.

Comment: Does this mean that all integers are interpreted initially as `int`? Is this a result of casting or just integrally how it is for numbers? @ikegami

Comment: Depends on what suffix they have `0` is an `int`, but `0u` is an `unsigned int`. `l` for `long`. `ll` for  `long long`. `l` and `ll` can be paired with `u` for the `unsigned` variant.

Comment: Is that simply because `0` can be held in an `int`, or is it integrally defined that way?

Comment: I replaced my comment above. The new one explains better.

Comment: Understood. So something like `~0u` could work in a one’s complement or sign magnitude system then, assuming truncation in a cast from `unsigned int` to `unsigned char`. If that’s the case then that’s probably the most portable/safest strategy.